# Openerp8 startup error: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, odoo, startup

I'm trying to run two instances of OpenERP on the same machine, but whenever I launch the second one it crashes. It is the same user that is launching the two instances of OpenERP and in the same postgresDB but, I launch each instance of OpenERP with different users in the database. Here is the log file I have no idea what is going on here:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/lib/python2.7/Werkzeug-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/home/user/lib/python2.7/Werkzeug-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/service/server.py", line 273, in app
return self.app(e, s)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 215, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 201, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/http.py", line 1097, in __call__
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/http.py", line 1074, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
File "/home/user/lib/python2.7/Werkzeug-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/http.py", line 1226, in dispatch
ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/http.py", line 220, in registry
return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 269, in get
update_module)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 299, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 335, in load_modules
force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 241, in load_marked_modules
graph.add_modules(cr, module_list, force)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/modules/graph.py", line 99, in add_modules
info = openerp.modules.module.load_information_from_description_file(module)
File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp8/openerp/modules/module.py", line 180, in load_information_from_description_file
terp_file = opj(mod_path, '__openerp__.py')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Path is bool type. Is path loaded from config?

Comment: Yeah I set a path from the configuration file

Comment: Somehow your path is bool. Check your config.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This may be due to port clash. Try running the instances on different ports, say one on 8069 and the other on 8070.</strike>

Try opening the instances in separate Icognito Window (while using chrome), or Private Browsing Window(while using mozilla), because there may be case of one instance overwriting the sessions of another openerp instance.
If this doesn't solve your problem, then I suggest you to pull the latest code of OpenERP8, as  still it is not stable.

Hope this helps, do update me with your feedback..

Comment: I'm running with different ports using `xmlrpc-port` also I'm using different users in the database.